# Connect anypoint platform to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, anypoint-platform, aws-vpc-peering, transit-gateway

MULESOFT-AWS

1. I have more than 5 API in anypoint platform but i just want only one API send information to my VPC on aws.
2. How can i send just the information from API in my enviroment (example: QA) to aws? NOTE: i have more than 4 API in this enviroment
3. On AWS my VPC is connect to my partner VPC with peering connection
4. How can i redirect the information once i recieve from anypoint platform to this peering connection?

I´ve tried transit gateway but i  think if i make a transit gateway affects the entire enviroment, i dont know if a can make a rule that make a condition to send information just from one API

how can i resend the information to the vpc peering

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by "sending information just from one API"? Is the communication with peering working? Why are the other APIs sending information if you don't want to? To what exactly are they sending that information? How the Anypoint environments are relevant? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear however I understand that you have several Mule applications deployed in CloudHub in an [Environment](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/environments), and you want only one of the applications to communicate with your internal network through the VPC Peering. This seems to be more of an infrastructure question. You should try other sites more suited for infrastructure questions.

Currently there is no built-in way to restrict the other applications to communicate with the internal network. There are some alternatives you may try:

- Deploy some applications to a different environment and associate the VPC to an environment for applications that are allowed to communicate.
- Implement some authentication scheme to prevent non authenticated application to use internal services. For example Mutual TLS Authentication. This doesn't prevent communication though from other applications. May require changes to your application and internal service.
- Your internal network may be able to implement some firewall rules by using the [internal DNS name](https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/cloudhub-networking-guide#dns-records) of the application (example: mule-worker-internal-myapp.region.cloudhub.io). Depends on the infrastructure that your company uses.